# How to add 2 attributes after select.options.add(new Option())

Tags: javascript

My select menu show the color name but with jQueryUI (custom.iconselectmenu) I like to add a avatar block with the corresponding color.
I can't figure out how to add the two attributes:

```
data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: none; background-color: (the rgb value)
```

in my code:

```
var data = [
    { text: 'Select a Color', value: '0' },
    { text: 'Antibes Green', value: 'rgb(95,173,72)' },
    ...
    { text: 'Versailles', value: 'rgb(206,204,130)' }
];

for(var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
    var d = data[j];
    select.options.add(new Option(d.text, d.value))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use [the `setAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) on the option, like this:

```
var option = new Option(d.text, d.value);
option.setAttribute('data-class', 'avatar');
option.setAttribute('data-style', 'background-image: none; background-color: ' + d.value);
select.options.add(option);
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ad1no8ou/

My preference is to avoid creating HTML using string concatenation due to the risk of bugs when you inevitably forget to escape special characters in the values that you are concatenating.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try these also.

Comment: I prefer this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line

```
select.options.add(new Option(d.text, d.value))
```

by

```
select.innerHTML += "<option value='" + d.text + "' data-class='avatar' data-style='background-image: none; background-color: (the rgb value)'>" + d.value +"</option>";
```